# Ethernet surge protector interrupting internet connection

Tags: repeater, power-over-ethernet, surge-protection

I'm having a problem with connecting a security camera to the internet. The connection is as follows:

Wifi repeater ethernet port -> POE injector -> ethernet surge protector -> camera.

With this configuration the camera is powered but does not have internet connectivity. If I take out the surge protector, everything works - i.e., internet and power. I've tried different surge protectors and they both interrupt the internet connection. I need to have a surge protector for lightning protection. What could be causing this?

Comment: What type of surge protector, a ['real' one](http://gwenergy.co.uk/surge-protection/) or just one in a regular mains extension cable? If the latter, it won't [vaguely protect against lightning](https://stormhighway.com/surge_protectors_ups_lightning_protection_myth.php), so just take it out.

Comment: Is the surge protector PoE compatible?

Comment: It is a real surge protector, and it is PoE compatible. I have another configuration at a different site that is router (not a repeater) -> PoE -> same surge protector -> camera and that works fine.

Comment: Are both ends of your PoE on the same ring main? Chances of them working between separate rings are low. I can't use them here [even though I got a box-full for free] because each floor is on a separate ring, sometimes 2 rings per floor… & my house comprises 5 floors :/ I had to hardwire ethernet throughout.

Comment: Have you tested the surge protector by itself? Without PoE?

Comment: The power is out at our site at the moment so I can't test anything, but I will try that.